# Film ideas at 1 million fps?

Tags: video, video-recording

So I have access to a camera that can capture up to 5 million frames per second, that actually has decent resolution (924 x 768 pixels). One drawback is it will only capture 180 frames (less than 0.2 milli-seconds at 1 million frames per second). People use these camera for capturing cracks or bullets, for example. My question is, if you could use this camera for anything you liked, what would you film?

Comment: Lucky you. How is the camera triggered? That would be fairly crucial I'd imagine

Comment: Make sure you post a link to whatever you do!

Comment: Hi James, this type of question is better suited for a forum about video production rather than a Q&A site like Stackexchange, this type of question does not have a clear answer and is only encouraging long opinion based discussion. Which is great in a forum but not so great on a Q&A site :)

Comment: Very true. Feel free to close.

Answer (score 0):

Liquids are always an interesting subject matter. Maybe sparkling water.

Answer (score 0):

- Stuff blowing up obviously.
- Something fragile being hit very hard with a hammer.
- A lot of electricity suddenly flowing through something that probably shouldn't have a lot of electricity flowing through it.
- Fireworks.
- hitting explosive fireworks in a crystal vase with a hammer that is connected to a high voltage electricity supply